# Dramatic screen flickering with html5 video

Tags: android, cordova, html5-video

My Cordova application starts flickering screen when video is played, as seen here: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/XL-mNnKdyqfjaSX41cRokvJe6_O02b72eEbc6Bz7tWQc4Qz8Qimx94eC8x4sRRz7nWccN56crwsSKA=m37

- It appears to be associated with something in Cordova Android between 6.1.2 to 8.1.0 inclusive, as it immediately started appearing for existing users when they upgraded the app from our Cordova Android 6.1.2 version to an upgraded Cordova 9.0 version (and another person who I've encountered with the issue is encountering it on Android 8.1.0). Nothing in the Cordova Android changelogs seem to indicate modifications to video
- All users who have encountered it are running Chrome 83 and Android 9 or 10, but I haven't been able to replicate it myself.

*Environment, Platform, Device*:
Android platform, mostly on Samsung and OnePlus devices

*Cordova:*

- Cordova CLI : PhoneGap 7.0.0
- Cordova Platforms : android 9.0.0
- Cordova Plugins : c.fovea.cordova.purchase, com.hutchind.cordova.plugins.streamingmedia, com.phonegap.plugins.videoplayer, com.rjfun.cordova.plugin.nativeaudio.NativeAudio, cordova-plugin-device, cordova-plugin-dialogs, cordova-plugin-googleplus, cordova-plugin-health, cordova-plugin-inapppurchase, cordova-plugin-splashscreen, cordova-plugin-whitelist, de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification, nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing, org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser, org.apache.cordova.network-information

*System:*

- Android SDK Tools : 30.0.1
- NodeJS : v14.5.0
- npm : 6.14.5
- OS : MacOS 10.15.4

Comment: What do you mean by *PhoneGap 7.0.0*? Did you mean cordova@9.0.0? What is the cordova CLI version installed when you type **cordova -v** in the console?

Comment: it seems to be a chromium bug, is explained here https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1109016